# Cannot construct instance of `java.time.ZonedDateTime` (no Creators, like default construct, exist)

Tags: java, json, datetime, jackson, jax-rs

I'm learning Jackson under JAX-RS 1.0. The server returns a HTTP response as follows:

```
{
  "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/123",
  "created": "2018-05-26T09:21:26.301+02:00"
}
```

and I need to deserialize the JSON response into a Java object called `ProductCreated`:

```
public class ProductCreated {

  @JsonProperty("created")
  private final ZonedDateTime created;

  @JsonProperty("url")
  private final String url;

  public ProductCreated(String url) {
    this.url = url;
    this.created = ZonedDateTime.now();
  }

  @JsonCreator
  public ProductCreated(
      @JsonProperty("url") String url,
      @JsonProperty("created") ZonedDateTime created) {
    this.url = url;
    this.created = created;
  }

  public String getUrl() {
    return url;
  }

  public ZonedDateTime getCreated() {
    return created;
  }
}
```

In my test, it failed to construct the `ProductCreated` object:

```
Product p = new Product("123", "foo");
ProductCreated c = wr.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                     .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                     .post(ProductCreated.class, p);
```

And the client side error is:

> Cannot construct instance of `java.time.ZonedDateTime` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2018-05-26T09:21:26.301+02:00')

On the server side, I configured the JSON mapper (but no effect to my test since test is client side?):

```
private static JacksonJsonProvider newJacksonJsonProvider() {
  ObjectMapper mapper =
      new ObjectMapper()
          .registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
          .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
          .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()); // new module, NOT JSR310Module
  mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
  mapper.setDateFormat(new StdDateFormat());
  return new JacksonJsonProvider(mapper);
}
```

What am I missing here?

---

The full stack-trace:

```
objc[91369]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x10fe224c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x11164e4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
May 26, 2018 9:48:29 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.4 05/24/2017 03:46 PM'
May 26, 2018 9:48:31 AM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start
INFO: Started listener bound to [localhost:8080]
May 26, 2018 9:48:31 AM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
INFO: [HttpServer] Started.
May 26, 2018 9:48:31 AM io.mincong.shop.rest.MyRequestFilter filter
INFO: filter
May 26, 2018 9:48:31 AM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener stop
INFO: Stopped listener bound to [localhost:8080]

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.ZonedDateTime` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2018-05-26T09:48:31.622+02:00')
 at [Source: (sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream); line: 1, column: 50] (through reference chain: io.mincong.shop.rest.dto.ProductCreated["created"])

    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:644)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:586)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:686)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570)
    at io.mincong.shop.rest.ProductResourceIT.createProduct(ProductResourceIT.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.ZonedDateTime` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2018-05-26T09:48:31.622+02:00')
 at [Source: (sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream); line: 1, column: 50] (through reference chain: io.mincong.shop.rest.dto.ProductCreated["created"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1451)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1027)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(ValueInstantiator.java:371)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1366)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:171)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:161)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:529)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeWithErrorWrapping(BeanDeserializer.java:528)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:417)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1280)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:326)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:1574)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:965)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:815)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:634)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: Have you looked into https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8? I’ve got no experience with it, but it says it’s got “support for Java 8 date/time types (specified in JSR-310 specification)”, which would include `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: Please post the whole stacktrace? Is this a client side or server side error? And where are registering the `JacksonJsonProvider`? It needs to be registered both on the server and client side.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes I read the repo that you've pointed. I think the server side runs correctly thanks to jackson-modules-java8, but the client side failed to deserialize the data, because some annotations are missing.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I provided the whole stack trace. Indeed, I didn't register the `JacksonJsonProvider` on the client side, this might be the problem...

Comment: Yea, you can see in the stack trace that it is a client side error

Comment: @PaulSamsotha, many thanks. It works now!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As @PaulSamsotha pointed out, I need to register the JacksonJsonProvider on the client side too:

```
ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();
cc.getSingletons().add(ShopApplication.newJacksonJsonProvider());
wr = Client.create(cc).resource(Main.BASE_URI.resolve("products"));
```

which contains the customized solution:

```
private static JacksonJsonProvider newJacksonJsonProvider() {
  ObjectMapper mapper =
      new ObjectMapper()
          .registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
          .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
          .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()); // new module, NOT JSR310Module
  mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
  mapper.setDateFormat(new StdDateFormat());
  return new JacksonJsonProvider(mapper);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I was able to deserialize a JSON file with a ZonedDateTime with this code.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
MyObject myObject = objectMapper.readValue(new File("src/test/resources/data/my_object.json"), MyObject.class)
```

Comment: This also worked in Kotlin but with one addition : `objectMapper.registerModule(KotlinModule())` .

Comment: @GabrielBB it is failing with koltin also even after adding KotlinModule()