# Cannot deserialize String to Java object

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, lombok

(Data class) Entity.java

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Entity implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String status;
    private ZonedDateTime registrationDatetime;
    private ZonedDateTime updatedDatetime;
    private ZonedDateTime createdDatetime;
}
```

(Data class) Entities.java

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonDeserialize
public class Entities implements Serializable {
    private List<Entity> entities;
}
```

I tried to run this statement:

```
TypeReference<ResponseModel<Entities>> typeReference = new TypeReference<ResponseModel<Entities>>() {};
ResponseModel<Entities> response = objectMapper.readValue(result.getResponse().getContentAsString(), typeReference);
```

And I got this error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `model/Entities` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

I already put `@JsonDeserialize` and also `implements Serializable` what did I miss?

Comment: Try giving @NoArgsConstructor also for Entities class

Comment: Thanks,it's works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving @NoArgsConstructor also for Entities class. This should work.

Comment: I still got an error said: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.ZonedDateTime`

Comment: Refer this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50540403/cannot-construct-instance-of-java-time-zoneddatetime-no-creators-like-defaul @AussawinKaokum