# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDate

Tags: java, json, junit, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm facing an error while deserialize the string to object.

> org.opentest4j.MultipleFailuresError: Multiple Failures (2 failures)
>     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
>   construct instance of `java.time.LocalDate` (no Creators, like default
>   construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to
>   deserialize from String value ('2020-05-20')  at [Source: (String)

JSON

```
 {
       "studentId":57,
       "JoinedDate":"31-12-2019",
       "DOB":"08-06-1998"  

    }
```

Model

```
public class Student{

    private long studentId ;

    private LocalDate JoinedDate;

    private LocalDate DOB ;

    public long getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(long studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    public LocalDate getJoinedDate() {
        return JoinedDate;
    }

    public void setJoinedDate(LocalDate joinedDate) {
        JoinedDate = joinedDate;
    }

    public LocalDate getDOB() {
        return DOB;
    }

    public void setDOB(LocalDate dOB) {
        DOB = dOB;
    }
```

Unit Test Class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Main.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class StudentTest{


private Student student;
private ObjectMapper jsonObjectMapper;
@Before
public void setUp() throws IOException {

    jsonObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    jsonObjectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"));
    studentJson = IOUtils.toString(getClass().getResourceAsStream(CommonTestConstants.StudentPath+ "/Student.json"));


student = jsonObjectMapper.readValue(studentJson , Student.class);
}
```

Any one please advise

Reference 
[Cannot construct instance of `java.time.ZonedDateTime` (no Creators, like default construct, exist)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50540403/cannot-construct-instance-of-java-time-zoneddatetime-no-creators-like-defaul)

[Unable to Deserialize - Jackson LocalDate/Time - JUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62233024/unable-to-deserialize-jackson-localdate-time-junit?noredirect=1#comment110065384_62233024)

Comment: Please update the question with code where you are deserializing the json to pojo.

Comment: @Smile - I have updated question with mapping part

Answer (score 1):

1. Include jackson jsr310 module.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Register `JavaTimeModule`

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

3. Mark the `LocalDate` type fields in your java class with following annotations.

```java
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
```

---

**Complete code would be:**

Main class or junit :

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        Student student = objectMapper.readValue(YOUR_JSON_STRING, Student.class);
        System.out.println(student);
    }
```

Student:

```java
public class Student {

    private long studentId;

    @JsonProperty("JoinedDate")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDate JoinedDate;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDate DOB;

    // getters and setters and ToString
}
```

Comment: Thanks you So much @Smile - I tried your suggestion - I'm getting a error - org.opentest4j.MultipleFailuresError: Multiple Failures (2 failures)
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "2020-05-20": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2020-05-20' could not be parsed at index 2
 at [Source: (String)"    Can you please adivse?

Comment: Looks like you are trying with data which has date which is of different format than the one mentioned in question - dd-MM-yyyy. Isn't there any fixed date format which you expect in your json?

Comment: Thanks for quick turn around - Format I passing in json is correct 31-02-2019. But I guess LocalDate format is not accepting dd-MM-yyyy - It expecting default formant - Exception I'm getting org.opentest4j.MultipleFailuresError: Multiple Failures (2 failures)
 java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-12-31' could not be parsed at index 4

Comment: I hope you are using `LocalDateDeserializer` and not `LocalDateTimeDeserializer` in the annotation in `Student` class.

Comment: Yes @Smile- I'm using LocalDateDeserializer only

Comment: Can you update the question with minimum working code which reproduces this error?

Comment: Thank you so much @Smile- I debugged and Fixed the issue now - I just curious without including   this attribute in model   @JsonProperty("JoinedDate")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)  Any other centralized way  to achieve the same in Unit test project configuration ?

Comment: Check this answer for global configuration of LocalDate https://stackoverflow.com/a/51546069/1776132